# Image synchronisation in a single Region

Tags: fiware, fiware-glancesync

I would know something about fiware-glancesync component. I would like to synchronise only one image. I mean, I want to synchronise one single image in a region without modifying the current configuration file. How can I define a new configuration parameters (if it is possible) to do it with the GlanceSync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm used to select the images can be defined by the user. The easiest
and best way to suncrhonise only one or a set of images is modifying the  **glancesync.conf** configuration file inside *./conf* directory. I recomend the creation of a new section *[test]* in order that you do not modify the current *[master]* section. Just write the following lines:

```
    [test]
    metadata_condition = image.name == 'GIS_GE'
    credential= admin,<your secret>,http://130.206.112.3:5000/v2.0,admin
```

Keep in mind that '*130.206.112.3*' is the IP of the keystone service inside the FIWARE Lab, and the first and second *admin* are the *OS_USERNAME* and *OS_TENANT_NAME*. Last but not least '*your secret*' is the password in base64 format.

And then, only execute the command:

```
    ./sync.py test:<name of the node, e.g. Lannion2>
```

See documentation in [GlanceSync - Glance Synchronization Component](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-glancesync#how-the-images-to-be-synchronised-are-selected) in order to know more details about the image synchronization.

If you can obtain more information about the configuration of the GlanceSync, take a look to [GlanceSync Configuration](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-glancesync#configuration).